ng build command generating index.csr.html instead of index.html
I used to run ng build to produce a build for my Angular 18 application. It always worked fine, generating an index.html file. However, today it suddenly started generating an index.csr.html file instead, and I can't figure out why.
I use Firebase Hosting and a GitHub Action to automatically deploy the build. Since it is not generating an index.html, the deployment fails. Everything was running fine until yesterday.
To work around this issue, I have to manually rename index.csr.html to index.html, and then the deployment works fine.
Following is the output to the ng build command.
Application bundle generation complete. [15.184 seconds]

▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/esm/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/internal.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


▲ [WARNING] Module 'faye-websocket' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


csr is a known term in angular and stands for "client side rendering". This doesn't help you in the first place but: is there something in the configuration you changed? Any npm updates or something?

After enabling SSR, index.html contains a prerendered page. Additionally a index.csr.html is generated, which only includes the scripts and styles without any prerendered content. Are you using prerendering / SSR in your project?

I just checked, and I have CSR enabled, but it was always enabled, nothing changed in specific. There was only one thing I did was, I generated a --prod build and that could be the turning point. But how do I fix it ?

I encountered a similar problem. I realized that to generate a simple index.html you need to turn off the SSR. I changed two fields in angular.json
     "prerender": false,
     "ssr": false


Form the source code of the CLI :
  /**
   * If SSR is activated, create a distinct entry file for the `index.html`.
   * This is necessary because numerous server/cloud providers automatically serve the `index.html` as a static file
   * if it exists (handling SSG).
   * For instance, accessing `foo.com/` would lead to `foo.com/index.html` being served instead of hitting the server.
   */
  const indexBaseName = path.basename(options.index);
  indexOutput = ssrOptions && indexBaseName === 'index.html' ? 'index.csr.html' : indexBaseName;

index.csr.html is created when you have SSR enabled but it still gives the possibility of using a so called "Client Side Rendering" which is a regular SPA app.

So, how do I tell it to generate an index.html and not index.csr.html ?

Turn off SSR like Andrii Pavlov proposed if you don't use it or manually rename index.csr.html to index.html

This is a huge breaking change though, something we are experiencing the pain off right now
