Why don't Angular ng build creates me a HTML file (Even though no build error)
I want to deploy my Angular app to firebase. However, I found that my ng build (with or without production flag) will not create me a proper index.html file that I can use for hosting.
This is my dist folder:

I also got rid of each and every warning/error that occurred while performing ng serve:

This is my angular.json file:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "golfapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/golfapp",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "whatwg-url",
              "sweetalert2",
              "@supabase/node-fetch"
            ],
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2MB",
                  "maximumError": "5MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20kB",
                  "maximumError": "40kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "golfapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "golfapp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I am hoping for help here, as I tried everything I am capable of to get it resolved. However, I was not successful.
Thanks upfront!

Resolved all syntax errors that occurred during ng build
Increased the budget to prevent the warnings during ng build
Added several packages to angular.json's allowedCommonJsDependencies


do you want to use server side rendering? because it is defined in your config and the result is an artifact for SSR

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78700539/ng-build-command-generating-index-csr-html-instead-of-index-html

Andrei and Eliseo, thanks a milion! The SSR was defaulted when I created a new angular project - disabling this did the trick!
In addition, the dist folder will still create the "browser" folder. I recommend to drag and drop all the files into the lower level (dist/<project_name>), so that the standard firebase routing fetch the file!
Everything is good now.

This question is similar to: ng build command generating index.csr.html instead of index.html. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
